# I need help to but things together where i have done the basic code but i cant link the data file to the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

[tThis image specifies the assignmnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1mQR.jpg)

I am assigned this assignment where my data is file is

1,x2,x3,y
1.4,2.2,7.9,-42.5
8.3,7.9,9.0,-134.8
-5.9,9.7,-5.9,-14.4
-9.2,-0.1,-2.3,72.4
5.5,0.4,7.2,-55.2
-9.3,2.1,4.5,42.3
6.7,-1.4,-1.6,-33.6
-5.8,5.3,-6.8,20.0
6.5,-1.1,8.7,-57.0

I need help to get the values asked for in the picture above

```
import numpy as np 

#read data

my_data = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', delimiter='\t')


#remove header row
my_data=np.delete(my_data,0,0)



# prepare x and y
x=my_data[:,0:2]
y=my_data[:,-1]

# we have x values in x array
# for this method we should add a colum of ones as a first column of x
n=len(x)
o=n*[1]
x=np.c_[o,x]

# define the transpose of x
xT=x.T

# find xx square matrix
xTx=xT.dot(x)

np.linalg.det(xTx)

# find the invers of this matrix
xTx_inv=np.linalg.inv(xTx)

# now find the solution
b=xTx_inv.dot(xT.dot(y))

# make prediction
yp=x.dot(b)

# consider a new observation
xn=np.array([1,4,5])
ypn=xn.dot(b)

# calculate errors
e=y-yp

# residual maker
M=np.eye(n)-x.dot(xTx_inv.dot(xT))
e=M.dot(y)

yT=y.T
sst=yT.dot(M.dot(y))

bT=b.T
ssr=bT.dot(xT.dot(M.dot(x.dot(b))))

sse=e.T.dot(e)

# coefficient of determination
R2=1-sse/sst
```

Comment: Please show us what your desired result looks like, but just show us an image.

Comment: well the code is presented above however I want to link my data i to it to find Find the 
 (xTx) square matrix,
(d) Find the inverse of 
 matrix,
(e) Find the regression parameter vector ,
(f) Find the predicted values ̂ (yp) for each observation ,
(g) Calculate the residuals (e), using the observed and predicted values of ,
(h) Plot the chart of errors by preparing the axis as “ax.plot(e,'o')”.

Comment: x1,x2,x3,y    1.4,2.2,7.9,-42.5    8.3,7.9,9.0,-134.8      -5.9,9.7,-5.9,-14.4 -9.2,-0.1,-2.3,72.4        5.5,0.4,7.2,-55.2      -9.3,2.1,4.5,42.3       6.7,-1.4,-1.6,-33.6 -5.8,5.3,-6.8,20.0         6.5,-1.1,8.7,-57.0

Comment: this is my data^^^